# How can I stop all sound in flash using AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What can I do to stop all sound in my movie using AS3?

Comment: SoundMixer.stopAll();

Answer (score 3):

you need to import flash.media.soundmixer, then you may run the command soundmixer.stopAll();

this should stop all the sounds.

Comment: Matt, why am I getting an error when I try to import it? Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 4, Line 1 1172: Definition flash.media:soundmixer could not be found.

Comment: I think it is just 
    import flash.media.Sound

Comment: It's `flash.media.SoundMixer` (capitalization)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution as well:

```
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
sTransform.volume = 0;
SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
```

Taken from [HERE](http://www.terrypaton.com/as3-mute-sounds-globally/)